# kadmin (through ambari) is not able to create principals, but kadmin.local is able to create

Tags: mit-kerberos

I am trying to kerberize my HDF 3.0 cluster. I have configured kerberos database, provided all sorts of permission in kadm5.acl & defined realm & other details properly in krb5.conf

Now the problem is through kadmin.local I am able to create required principals. But through kadmin, its giving following exception.

add_principal: Operation requires ``add'' privilege while creating "dbdhdf301-011518@EMEA.EBS.CORPINTRA.NET".

Kindly suggest me the resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it like this:
i tried kadmin from server. It logs in with default principal as :  admin/admin@EMEA.EBS.CORPINTRA.NET

So i edited the kadm5.acl file & provided complete permission.
*/admin@EMEA.EBS.CORPINTRA.NET *

Then restarted kdcadmind & krb5kdc. Then tested the connection again. It worked perfectly.